# Pyhton2.7.10:Using os.listdir() to print file names in a folder,but get noting on shell

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I want to print all files'name on the folder with the function os.listdir(),but I run the code for several time,these was nothing showed in shell

I'm using OS X 10.11.6

[image: Screen shot]

```
import os
def rename_files():
    #get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir('/Users/luoluoluo/Desktop/Udacity/Program funfation with python/prank')
    print(file_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call function `rename_files` when running the script. Add at the end of script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    rename_files()
```

[The reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html)